# Suggestion on iOS development

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an iOS app - which is basically content driven - which has categorized information. But yes, the content would be updated often - for which the users would be prompted with an alert, if they would like to update now or later. So the suggestions I need are:

1. The content is admin managed and the webservice is written in PHP & the backend is MySQL. 
   When users download the app - should the entire database be installed along with the app or should only the data be moved and stored in the device db?
2. When there's an update in the content - how would that be sync'ed with the device? Would there be a flag to detect the last update made?

Any help on this would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 3):

1) Since it's much easier and faster to update the data in your backend database, than in the app (due to the need to re-build and resubmit the app, the long approval process, etc.), it makes sense to deploy your app with an empty database that uses an appropriate data model (possibly using Core Data). Upon the first run, your app could download the most recent data from the web service.

2) Your app could store the timestamp of the last successful sync in the user preferences, and include that value in its requests to the web service, in order to get the incremental updates to the data from the service.

3) If you have a lot of data, I recommend designing the UI in such a way that it can display some data as soon as it arrives, while showing a clear message notifying the user that the syncing is still in progress. This way the user can start interacting with the app very quickly, but the app can still keep downloading the data in the background.

Comment: Yes, It's a nice idea. I use following process... 1) dowload database firstime app load. 2) Store every record with its modified timestamp. 3) everytime, When application will start , it will call webservice with parameter as Highest timestamp. If any records have been modified or insert it will be given webservice.

Comment: Thanks - the amount of data is really huge - possibly 100's of pages - which we would use a UIWebview to display. So, do you reckon the method you suggested is yet the way to go? Sorry, I should have mentioned to you about the data being quite large

Comment: @user1527987: if you have a lot of data, I recommend designing the UI in such a way that it can display **some** data as soon as it arrives, while showing a **clear** message notifying the user that the syncing is still in progress. This way the user can start interacting with the app very quickly, but the app can still keep downloading the data in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's a nice idea. I use the following process:

1) Download database the first time the app loads.

2) Store every record with its modified timestamp.

3) Every time the application starts, call the webservice with parameter as newest timestamp.

If any records have been modified or inserted it will be given webservice. For deleted records, each record has one delete flag. If it is true, the record is deleted.

Comment: Thanks - the amount of data is really huge - possibly 100's of pages - which we would use a UIWebview to display. So, do you reckon the method you suggested is yet the way to go? 
Sorry, I should have mentioned to you about the data being quite large